# Generate mysqldump without comments

Tags: mysql

I am generating a dump file form mysql using `mysqldump -u root -p --databases dbname > dump.sql`, and the file generated is as follows:

```sql
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.21, for osx10.15 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: dbname
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   8.0.21

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Current Database: `dbname`
--

CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `dbname` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci */ /*!80016 DEFAULT ENCRYPTION='N' */;

USE `dbname`;

--
-- Table structure for table `tbname`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbname`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `tbname` (
  `volume_no` int NOT NULL,
  `issue_no` int NOT NULL,
  `page_no` int NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`volume_no`,`issue_no`,`page_no`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

But this has many comments and info which I don't exactly need. Is there a way to directly get output without things like `/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;` etc. as despite being comments, these are generating errors when the file is executed from a python

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;` aren't really comments even though they look that way. They are conditional-execution tokens.

however you can skip comments by `--skip-comments` and you can try `--compact` as well

Comment: This does not remove those "SET character_set_client" comments in the table sections.

Comment: @DanieleTesta `--compact` removed everything for me. mysqldump  Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.7.38-41